# Mail forward: 550 5.7.1 Anonymous client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: email, postfix

I want to install a small mailing list that forwards mails related to a specific project to all project members. So, let's say there are two members in that project `userA@mailA.tld` and `userB@mailB.tld`, and on my mail server `server.tld` I configured an alias by adding a line to my virtual maps:

```
project23@server.tld    userA@mailA.tld,userB@mailB.tld
```

So far, everything works as expected. If I send an email to `project23@server.tld` it gets forwarded to all users in that project. But it turns out that certain mail servers don't like to receive mails from foreign mail servers containing a `From` claiming to be sent from their domain. (Seems like especially Microsoft's SMTP servers have this *problem*). In that case I get a response like:

```
 [...] said: 550 5.7.1 Anonymous client does not have permissions to send as this sender. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

That means `userA@mailA.tld` is able to receive mails sent to `project23@server.tld` by `userB@mailB.tld`, but won't receive any mails sent from addresses in `mailA.tld`.

So my first question is: Did I isolate the problem correctly?

And if so, is there any smart workaround?

I could setup a real mailing list, so that mails are stored in an archive on the server and users get notifications/digests from a mail address like `list@server.tld`, but that would be too much overhead for our purposes...

Answer (score 1):

## Postfix: simple mailing list

Have you tried to create owner-project23@server.tld entry in virtual maps?

As I understand It should make postfix change envelope sender ("send bounces to") address of messages send to project23@server.tld and fix your problem.

http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#mailing_lists

Comment: Doesn't the document behind link describe how to setup a full mailing list? I tried to avoid that..

Comment: Your problems boils down to being unable to deliver to the alias **without** changing envelope sender address. I have assumed that owner-* entry in virtual maps behaves like owner-* alias ( http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html ). The extra alias/entry should not require installing any mailing-list software.

Comment: Hi,

"But it turns out, that certain mail servers don't like to receive mails from foreign mail servers containing a `From` claiming to be sent from their domain."

Of course they don't like that!

But somehow I am missing something - how does that relate to the problem?